# Build Laravel + CoreUI + Vue error run command npm run dev

Tags: laravel, vue.js, core-ui

I use template CoreUI (https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-vue-admin-template) with laravel 5.7 (or 5.6).
I run command

```
npm run dev
```

Error in file

> E:/xampp/htdocs/laravel56/resources/assets/js/admin/router/index.js
>   And row

```
const DefaultContainer = () => import('@/containers/DefaultContainer')
```

Error

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/admin/router/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: E:/xampp/htdocs/laravel56/resources/assets/js/admin/router/index.js: Unexpected token (5:31)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show us the `code` of your `router/index.js` file?

Comment: Thanks Julian Paolo Dayag, I install dynamic import (https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node) and run ok now.

Comment: Oh, that's good. You should convert it into an answer to make it formal.